# Use members of a base class provided as a template parameter without qualifiers

Tags: c++

This code works:

```
struct Defs
{
    static const int a = 1;
    int b{};
    void g() {}
};

struct Bob : Defs
{
    void f()
    {
        cout << a << "\n";
        cout << b << "\n";
        g();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bob b;
    b.f();
}
```

But this code doesn't:

```
struct Defs
{
    static const int a = 1;
    int b{};
    void g() {}
};

template<class D>
struct Bob : D
{
    void f()
    {
        cout << a << "\n";
        cout << b << "\n";
        g();
    }
};

int main()
{
    Bob<Defs> b;
    b.f();
}
```

Errors:

```
prog.cpp: In member function 'void Bob<D>::f()':
prog.cpp:16:11: error: 'a' was not declared in this scope
   cout << a << "\n";
           ^
prog.cpp:17:11: error: 'b' was not declared in this scope
   cout << b << "\n";
           ^
prog.cpp:18:5: error: there are no arguments to 'g' that depend on a template parameter, so a declaration of 'g' must be available [-fpermissive]
   g();
     ^
prog.cpp:18:5: note: (if you use '-fpermissive', G++ will accept your code, but allowing the use of an undeclared name is deprecated)
```

But if I do the following, it works:

```
template<class D>
struct Bob : D
{
    void f()
    {
        cout << D::a << "\n";
        cout << D::b << "\n";
        D::g();
    }
};
```

Is it possible to get a class to use the members of a base class provided as a template parameter, without qualifying them? The reason I ask is because doing so would allow me to refactor some code without a LOT of changes.

It can be assumed the type used as the template parameter has all those members, otherwise a compile failure is acceptable.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

#### Introduction

You get the error because the base-class is *dependent* on a *template-parameter*, which isn't too surprising since the base-class is the direct use of the *template-parameter*.

The error diagnostic comes from the fact that different *template-parameters* could yield significantly different behavior inside the class; what if the passed in *template-parameter* doesn't have a certain member; are we then to look up something in the global scope?

- [Where and why do I have to put the “template” and “typename” keywords?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/24101297/1090079)

---

#### Explicitly state that you would like to access a member of `this`

You are saying that you would like to access members of the base-class without qualifying them, and if I were to take you literally on this I would say that you could use `this->member-name` — but I doubt that this is what you are after given what you wrote about refactoring.

```
struct A { 
  int m;
};
```

```
template<class T>
struct B : T { 
  void func () {
    this->m = 1;
  }
};
```

```
int main () {
  B<A> {}.func (); 
}
```

---

#### Bring in names from the *dependent* base-class

Another alternative is to explicitly state that you would like certain names from your base-class to be available directly in that which derives from it— using `using`, as in the below:

```
template<class T>
struct B : T {
  using T::m;

  void func () {
    m = 1;
  }
};
```

The above can be read as; *"dear compiler, wherever I'm referring to `m` I would like you to use the one in `T`"*.

---

#### But I want to hack the shit out of this problem; how!?

Alright, introduce a non-dependent base and have that introduce *references* to the data that you really want. This will work if you know what names that you will want to pull in for every `T`.

You can even extend this hack to automatically have it deduce the type of those members, but that is far away from the scope of the question.

```
#include <iostream>

struct A {
  int n;
  int m;

  void print () {
    std::cout << m << std::endl;
  }
};
```

```
struct Hack {
  template<class T>
  Hack (T* hck) : m (hck->m), n (hck->n) { }
  int& m;
  int& n;
};
```

```
template<class T>
struct B : T, Hack {
  B () : Hack (static_cast<T*> (this)) { }

  void func () {
    m = 123;
  }
};
```

```
int main () {
  B<A> b;
  b.func ();
  b.print ();
}
```

You can find a running example [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/54d82fd2c076e3cd). Word of warning; I would personally never do this, but as you can see it is possible to do what you ask through a little bit of indirection.

Comment: @sehe [**You know I'm bad, I'm bad - you know it!**](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dsUXAEzaC3Q)

Answer (score 3):

You can add:

```
using D::a;
using D::b;
using D::g;
```

to `Bob` to fix your scoping issue.

[Here](https://isocpp.org/wiki/faq/templates#nondependent-name-lookup-members) is a comprehensive overview of this problem. Honestly, it's a corner of C++ that shouldn't exist, but, no language is perfect =P

Comment: Hm any way around it without needing to add that to many classes?

Comment: @NeilKirk Not really, no. You can either add the `using D::`s to the class or in the scope where you use those variables, or refer to the variables using `this->` or `D::` every time. Those are the options.

Comment: @NeilKirk see the section titled *"But I want to hack the shit out of this problem; how!?"* in my answer; added just for you.

Comment: @FilipRoséen-refp that hack more code and far less clear than just writing `using D::a` for each variable.

Comment: @David not if you have a lot of classes where you need that, which I assume since otherwise *OP* is just lazy (if he can't be bothered to change that for a single class).